# Property of object is showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I assign this empty array to a property of an object, so I can reference it using dot notation later?

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/ckdfyfxp/

```
var AJAX_Utils_AddressBook = {
    contacts: null
};

var contact = [];
AJAX_Utils_AddressBook.contacts = contact;

console.log(AJAX_Utils_AddressBook.contacts.contact.length);
```

This is the error I'm getting ..

```
AJAX_Utils_AddressBook.contacts.contact is undefined
```

Comment: you are assigning it to contacts, not a contact property of contacts

Comment: You're not appending `contact` to `contacts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no object contact in contacts.

You would access it with:

```
console.log(AJAX_Utils_AddressBook.contacts.length);
```

---

For your line to work, your code would need to look like

```
var contact = [];
AJAX_Utils_AddressBook.contacts = { contact: contact };
```